# Checkout maven dependency as module in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project that is broken down in a bunch of dependencies, some of which I have RW access to the version control repository.

I'd like switch one from being a read-only dependency to a full project module. Is it possible for IDEA to use the data contained in the POM to do this? I heard that NetBeans does this.

Comment: You can add a new module to the project and the module can be created from `pom.xml` (**Import Module from External Model**).

Comment: Hi, that's not exactly what I was thinking of, but is close. I'd like to magically use use the pom.xml of the Maven dependency for the Import action...

Comment: You can submit a request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this, too.  We have a framework we built in house and it's often convenient to modify it while we modify the project we're working on.  The best thing we've come up with is to checkout the framework and include it as an IntelliJ module and a module tag in the pom.  As long as the version numbers match and they're snapshot, intellij seems to use the source of the module instead of the dependency. Just don't commit that pom on accident

Comment: Currently it's not possible, so I opened a feature request for it. You can track it on http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94785